# How to animate div with two directions at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I will need to animate this div in two directions at the same time , but it only animates to the first property.

```
function  plan11() {   
$('.plan1').animate({ left : windowWidth, top: '10px;'},60000, "linear", function() {
  $('.plan1').delay(1000).animate({ left: "-83" },30000,"linear"); medium() ; }); } 
    plan11();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You see only the `left` movement or only the `top` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the ; in the 'top' property:

```
function plan11() { 
    $('.plan1').animate({ left : windowWidth, top: '10px'}, 60000, "linear", 
    function() {
        $('.plan1').delay(1000).animate({ left: "-83" }, 30000, "linear"); 
        medium();
    }); 
}

plan11();
```

Comment: THanks @Stefan :) LoL ,the ; was the error , ohhhh i should learning the OOP from the start :D thanks again